# Auth::User() gives null in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am new to laravel. I am using multi authentication in my application. User and Admin are 2 type of user in my application. Iam developing change password for admin after logged in to application through admin's profile page. now I want to get logged in admin user detail so that i have use below code in my controller

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        $user = Auth::id();
        echo '<pre>';
        dd($user);
        exit;
    }
```

I have also add following code in controller

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Adminauth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Admin;
use Session;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
```

In route.php i have write following code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
//Login Routes...
Route::auth();
Route::get('admin/profile/change_password', 'Admin\AdminController@change_password');
```

});

But i am not able to get admin user detail. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: what does dd($user) results into?

Comment: use  `$user = Auth::user();' instead `$user = Auth::id();`

Comment: dd($user); gives null result

Comment: I have use $user = Auth::id(); still same problem

Comment: Can I see the login controller ?

Comment: I have use basic authentication not through controller.
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Adminauth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Adminauth\AuthController@login');

Comment: try to put Route::auth(); outside the middleware group

Comment: You are setting `Route::auth();` when the user is already loggedin.

Comment: I have remove `Route::auth();` out of that code.

Comment: Does it work this way?

Comment: @AdarshBhatt you can write this `$user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();` and then `dd($user);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function __construct() {
$this->middleware('auth:admin');
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
$user = $this->user = Auth::user();
dd($user);
});
}
```

In routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
     return view('auth.login');
});
```

Comment: it gives me Illegal offset type error in controller.php

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` is working only under `auth` middleware. You may call `auth` middleware on controller or call it on routes, but not on both.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')
    }
    
    public function yourFunction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

Route::get('your-uri', function () {
    $user = \Auth::user();
    dd($user);
})->middleware('auth');
```